# SpriteKit SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, variables, sprite-kit

```
func repulseFire() {
if let zombieGreen =  self.childNode(withName: "zombie") as? SKSpriteNode {
    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "repulse") {
        node, stop in
        if let repulse = node as? SKSpriteNode {
        if let action = zombieGreen.action(forKey: "zombieAction") {
                action.speed = 0
                func run() {
                    action.speed = 1
                }
                var dx = CGFloat(zombieGreen.position.x - repulse.position.x)
                var dy = CGFloat(zombieGreen.position.y - repulse.position.y)
                let magnitude = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
                dx /= magnitude
                dy /= magnitude
                let vector = CGVector(dx: 25.0 * dx, dy: 25.0 * dy)
                func applyImpulse() {
                zombieGreen.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(vector)
                }
                zombieGreen.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.run(applyImpulse), SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.2), SKAction.run(run)]))
            }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to hit back the zombies when this function is called. The only issue is that there are more than one zombie on the scene at some points in time and the impulse is only applied to the zombie that spawned before the others on the screen. How can I make it so that all the zombies are affected? I think it has to do with the line "if let zombieGreen =  self.childNode(withName: "zombie") as? SKSpriteNode"

Comment: You are enumerating a wrong guy.

Comment: What is this 'repulse' node? Also, you will pick up only the first 'zombie' node - is that what you want? do you not need another `enumerateChidNode` loop to pick up all the zombies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using an Array to store the zombie when you add them to the scene. This is faster then enumerating the scene and gives you more flexibility.

```
// create an array of spriteNodes
    var zombieArray:[SKSpriteNode]

    //add zombies to array when you add them to scene
    zombieArray.append(zombieGreen)

    //check if any zombies are in the scene
    if zombieArray.count > 0{
        .....
    }

    //Do something with all the zombies in the array - your main question.
    for zombie in zombieArray{

        .....
        zombie.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(vector)
    }

    // remove zombie from array
    zombieArray.remove(at: zombieArray.index(of: theZombieYouWantToRemove))
```

Comment: "This is faster then enumerating the scene" - interesting. How did you find this out?. How much faster is it?

Comment: well. If you enumerate the scene you will loop trough all nodes in the scene. including trees, buildings, clouds or whatever your scene is composed of. And since we are only looking for zombies and array with only zombies would exclude all the other stuff in the scene. this might not really be a problem with a simple scene. but when there is a lot of stuff in the scene it will make a difference @SteveIves

Comment: So it making a difference is pure conjecture? So you have your zombie array - what happens when you want to process all 'attacking zombies'? do you have another array for that? and then all zombies within a 1/4 screen's width of the player? I think this is a case of premature optimisation.

Comment: Thats exactly why you should put the zombies in an array. if you want to do many things like checking distance from tower to zombie, run some functions on all zombies, etc. Then you access the zombies from the zombiearray instead of looping through ALL the elements in the whole scene.

Comment: My point is suppose you don't want the zombies but something else? What then - another array? An array of all attacking zombies? Do you build an array of every possible node search? `enumerateChildNodes` takes a name parameter to restrict what it returns. I'd be very surprised if its optimisation doesn't beat searching a standard array. I'd be even more surprised if there is any real-world difference, which is why I'd like to see some figures to back this up or a project to demonstrate slowdown that can be avoided. I think you've introduced complexity for no gain.

Comment: Okay I get your point. I did some test in terms of performance. 200 zombie nodes and 200 unrelated nodes added to the scene. only the zombie nodes were put in an array. Looping the scene with enumratChildNodes gives a CPU usage of 7%. Looping the array gives a usage of 1%. (looping every frame).  if this has any real-world difference really depends on the rest of the game. lets say 50 towers and A tilemap of 150 tiles(not sure if it counts as separate nodes, but..) and then run the enumerate twice in every update. 14% vs 2% could make difference.

Comment: and for the separate array for different monsters? sure if you want to optimise even more. but you would probably have both zombies and skeletons in the same monsters array

Comment: If I wanted to find the closest zombie, how could I compared the distances away from the tower of each zombie in the array?

Comment: `let prevDistanice:CGFloat = 1000000
let closesetZombie = zombieArray[0]
for zombie in zombieArray{
   let distance = hypot(zombie.position.x - tower.position.x, 
   zombie.position.y - tower.position.y)
if distance < prevDistanice{
 prevDistance = distance
cloesestZombie = zombie
}
}`

Answer (score 0):

**All zombies affected by All repulse node in scene**

```
func repulseFire() {
    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "zombie") {
            zombieGreen, stop in {

            self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "repulse") {
                node, stop in
                //etc
```

**All zombies affected by ONE repulse node in scene**

```
func repulseFire() {
    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "zombie") {
            node, stop in {
        if let repulseNode =  self.childNode(withName: "repulse") {
            //etc
```